# MySQL SELECT top 10 and sort by this value

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, group-by, inner-join

Here is an interesting issue I came across while developing a ranking system.

Three tables:

1. Users (id, age, ...)
2. Routes (id, difficulty, ...)
3. Log (id, user_id, route_id, points, date, ...)

---

The goal is **to produce a list of users sorted by the amount of points they  have received for their top 10 logs**. For every user I have to find his/her top 10 logs (sorted by points) and then sort all the users by this number.

I also have to be able to limit the routes and users which are taken in account by other parameters -> age of the user, difficulty of the route, date of the log. For example create this ranking list out of all users older than 25 who added routes of difficulty 1-8, which are not older than a month (the logs).

This is as far as I got so far:
 1. I know how to select and sort the users based on the total amount of points:

```
SELECT 
    l.id, l.idr,
    u.name,..., ...,
    SUM(l.points) as totalPoints
FROM logs l
INNER JOIN routes r ON l.idr = r.id
INNER JOIN users u ON d.idu = u.id
WHERE
  /*
  All the conditions I need
  */

GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY totalPoints DESC
```

2. Select the top 10 for one user:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(points)
   FROM (
       SELECT l.points as points
       FROM logs l
       INNER JOIN users u ON l.idu = u.id
       WHERE u.id = '1'
       LIMIT 10
   ) AS T
   ```

I just don't know how to put these to together efficiently. I have solved this through some TEMPORARY TABLES and requesting additional data in while loop in PHP, but that's very very slow and inefficient. As the database is growing bigger (logs ~ 40 000, users ~ 2 000, routes ~ 1 000 records), more efficient solution is needed.

As I mentioned I'm working with PHP so if you have some idea how to make this faster (more efficient) not by creating one awesome query but rather by few more smart small ones and some in PHP, that would be really coll as well.

Thanks for any ideas :)

Comment: See [_Groupwise Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a correlated count subquery to calculate a ranking column which you then can use as filter in outer query. Had MySQL supported window functions, the usual approach would the`RANK OVER()` CTE solution.

Below are two examples by *user* and then by *user* and *route*. Notice with each grouping level, you add `WHERE` clauses to rank subquery and `GROUP BY` columns in the `t` derived table. The same goes for every special `WHERE` condition as they must be mirrored in subquery.

**User** *(top 10 overall logs for each user)*

```sql
SELECT main.`user`, main.totalPoints
FROM
  (SELECT t.name as `user`, SUM(t.points) as totalPoints
   FROM
      (SELECT l.id, l.idr, u.name, l.points,
             (SELECT Count(*) FROM logs sub
              WHERE sub.idu = l.idu
              AND sub.points >= l.points) AS user_rank 
       FROM logs l
       INNER JOIN users u ON l.idu = u.id) AS t
   WHERE t.user_rank <= 10
   GROUP BY t.name) AS main
ORDER BY main.totalPoints
```

**User and Route**  *(top 10 logs for each route for each user)*

```sql
SELECT main.`user`, main.route, main.totalPoints
FROM
  (SELECT t.name as `user`, t.idr as route, SUM(t.points) as totalPoints
   FROM
      (SELECT l.id, l.idr, u.name, l.points,
             (SELECT Count(*) FROM logs sub
              WHERE sub.idu = l.idu
              AND sub.idr = l.idr
              AND sub.points >= l.points) AS user_route_rank 
       FROM logs l
       INNER JOIN routes r ON l.idr = r.id
       INNER JOIN users u ON l.idu = u.id) AS t
   WHERE t.user_route_rank <= 10
   GROUP BY t.name, t.idr) AS main
ORDER BY main.totalPoints
```

Notes:

1. **TIES**: Log points that tie ARE included in this approach. There are methods for tiebreakers like taking the lowest primary key as shown here:

   ```sql
   (SELECT Count(*) FROM logs sub
    WHERE sub.idu = l.idu
    AND sub.idr = l.idr
    AND (sub.points >= l.points
         OR sub.points = l.points AND sub.id <= l.id))  AS user_route_rank
   ```
2. **GROUP BY**: Your above incomplete `GROUP BY` aggregation was removed. MySQL allows it but would have failed in every other RDMS. Had you had either [`ANSI` or `ONLY FULL GROUP BY` mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-full) on, MySQL would have raised an error since non-aggregated columns in `SELECT` clause of an aggregate query must also be included in `GROUP BY` (though the reverse is valid in ANSI).